# How to see other classes variables when debugging on Flash CS5.5?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, debugging

I'm trying to debug an actionscript 3.0 application, but I can't see static variables from other classes than the one where the code currently is.

For example, if I have this:

```
public class Main extends Sprite{
     public static var myVar:Number = 12
}
public class theBreakPointReliesOnThisClass {
>>breakpoint<< public function executeALotOfThingsBasedOnExternalVar ():void {
          if(Main.myVar == 12) {
               //stuff to execute
           }
       }
}
```

How can I access Main.myVar from the debugger? I would also like to change it's value on runtime. Is that possible with Flash IDE?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you [Monster Debugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/), it will allow you changing values of variables at runtime.

Comment: @Lucas yah it should, you just need to add the swc dependency and init the MonsterDebugger class and run monster debugger, I don't think there's any reason this won't work.  http://demonsterdebugger.com/tour/link-swc